# Why my insert method is giving a java.lang.StackOverflowError, while I am making Heap.

Tags: java, sorting, heapsort

I am making a simple program on Heap Sort.  Please review my code, and let me know my error. It maybe that I am using the wrong approach.  Thanks in advance.

The insert method take two arguments. Integer key is the element which I need to insert and Integer i is the index of the key which is in another array(i.e. Main class).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer arr[]={81,67,78,59,32,8,96};
    Main a =new Main();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    a.insert(arr[i], i);
    }

 public void insert(Integer key, Integer i) {
    int head=0;
    if(temp[head]==null)
    {
    temp[head]=key;
    }
    else
        {
        if(key>=temp[head]){
            Integer j=(2*i)+2;
            i=j;
            insert(key, i);    
        }
        else
        {

        Integer j=(2*i)+1;//Stackoverflow error is coming over here. 
        i=j;
        insert(key,i);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, you call the method again with another `i`, but you do not use `i` at all in the method, so it's like you call the method again with exactly the same arguments, thus infinite recursion.

Comment: you don't have terminating condition for your recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that, other than for the first element, inserting another element will cause your method to keep calling itself for ever since all your execution paths lead to the method being called again, with the exception for when the element at 0 is null.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as temp[0] is not null and the key is bigger or equal temp[0] you run into an infinite recursion.

Comment: First of: What is temp? And what is the insert method meant to do and why?

Comment: insert method is picking up the numbers from the array in the main class and making a simple binary tree(not via nodes rather arrays). For example if my array in main class is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} so my output should be a binary tree inform of array. I hope you get it.

Comment: Ok so you are trying to implement what the [Heapsort Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) calls 'heapify'. Unfortunately I can't see where your code matches the pseudocode there, but I found a reference implementation [HERE](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/09/heapsort-array-based-implementation-in.html)